# Display table from a datatable or dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a web project in VS 2010 and I am quite new to programming. I was just wondering how to display the data from a datatable or dataset in the web page once button_click event is fired/clicked?

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick code sample to get you started:

**ASPX**

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" ID="btnSubmit" 
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="unitCost" HeaderText="Cost"  dataformatstring="${0:F2}" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
        public void BindData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("productName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("unitCost", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Pineapple", 1.45);
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Apple", 1.45);
            dt.Rows.Add(17, "Orange", 6.33);
            dt.Rows.Add(23, "Pear", 17.32);
            dt.Rows.Add(27, "Banana", 12.20);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }
```

There are so many different ways to go about what you are trying to do but the above will give you a quick introduction.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it...  One of it is to use the DataGrid Control...  You can see the example [here...](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anjudidi/308062009080934AM/3.aspx)

There are other data controls like [Repeater](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater) etc, which could also be used...